# PLS package for R version 3.4.4

Tags: r

I maintain a code base which works on R version 3.4.4. I am trying to use the R package `pls`. But I can't install and use this package on this version.

code

```
install.packages("pls")
```

returns
Warning message: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
there is no package called ‘pls’

Is there any way I can get pls package version which is compatible with R 3.4.4?

Comment: Have you tried via the github version ? `library(devtools);
install_github("khliland/pls")`

Answer (score 1):

There is an archive on CRAN with all old versions of the packages.
Try this:
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/pls/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Package isn't archived, so this is useful but not directly useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's (probably) not that the package is incompatible or archived/no longer available, it's that CRAN isn't making a binary version available for R versions this old (I'm not quite sure why it doesn't fall back to the source version when the binary's not available: what is `getOption("pkgType")` on your system? I thought the default was "both" ... see `?install.packages`).

In particular, if you go to the [package web page on CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=pls) and in particular to the [source tarball](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/pls_2.8-1.tar.gz), you can download/open the tarball and inspect the DESCRIPTION file, particularly these lines:

```
Depends: R (>= 2.10)
Imports: grDevices, graphics, methods, stats
...
NeedsCompilation: no
```

This is good news: (1) the "strong dependencies" (Depends/Imports) don't rule out your version of R, and don't include any packages that aren't automatically installed with R (so you won't get into dependency hell); (2) there is no compiled code in the package (so you don't have to mess around with installing development tools).

Worth trying (not easy for me to test): use `install.packages()` with the URL of the source tarball and `repos = NULL`:

```r
install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/pls_2.8-1.tar.gz', 
                 repos = NULL)
```

It's also possible that `install.packages("pls", type = "source")` will just work, although in that case I'm not sure why any of your *other* package installs are working ... ?